# Regular expression to find string, then replace it with the same string and an additional character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, regexp-replace

I have the following dataset:

```
{ 16812},
{ 16812},
{ 16813},
{ 16819},
{ 16812},
{value 16812},
{value 16812]},
```

and I need to match and replace occurrences of { number} with { number | }.

I have the following regular expression that works:
`\{\s\d(?:[\d]*\.\d+|[\d]*)\}`

demo:
https://regex101.com/r/I4R4Hh/1

however is there a way to replace the match with the same value plus a pipe.
the number could be any number up to six digits, so I can't replace with a generic number as I need to maintain the number I have matched.

I am using python 3 with a pandas dataframe

Comment: You can put the number-matching part ofthe regex in parentheses `(...)`, then use \1 in the replacement

Comment: Besides I think you could reduce your pattern to `\{\s\d+(?:\.\d+)?\}` (at least there is no need to put `\d` on its own into a character class)

Comment: check https://regex101.com/r/I4R4Hh/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
import re

text = "{ 16812}"
text = re.sub(r'\{(\s\d(?:[\d]*\.\d+|[\d]*))\}', r'{\1 |}', text)

print(text) # { 16812 |}
```

Comment: this does the trick, thank you. I had to modify it slightly to get it working with my dataframe. this is my line of code:

`
  df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\{(\s\d(?:[\d]*\.\d+|[\d]*))\}', r'{\1 | }',  regex=True)
`